# Why thread is stopped when start new process, while application (c#) is still running?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process, process.start

Is there any problem which i have to do carefully when starting new process in multiple thread application?

I tried this in a simple project:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process.Start(@"D:\System\Desktop\a.txt");
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
```

And it runs perfectly. But when i do it in my big project which use multiple thread, it's thread is stopped working ("a.txt" is opened but "Success" is not shown) while my application (other thread) do well.

What is the problem in this situation?

Comment: Could you try Console.Writeline("Success"); instead, and see if that works?

Comment: I tried. Same result! After starting that process, everything in that thread are stopped!

Comment: Hmm, I'm unable to reproduce this... I made a thread that opens a process and puts a message to Console, and it works as it should... Anything else you are doing? Could you please try putting a breakpoint before the process.start and then step through to see if it really stops (because it shouldnt)

Comment: yes, the thread isn't stop working. But it doesn't process any more, any code after that, any return value.... same as stopped. I can't understand what's wrong. Here is my function:  'private string RunNormal(string fullfilename)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(fullfilename);
                return fullfilename + "|Success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return fullfilename + "|" + e.ToString();
            }
        }'

Comment: is your larger project a Console App or a Windows application you want to look at creating perhaps a semiphore and if worse comes to worse throw some Thread.Sleep(1000) for example in there

Comment: In my project, the main thread calls some process.start(...), all of them run well. I don't set any thread properties or any thing else. in my function above, funny, it can't catch the error when i open wrong file name.

Comment: How are you calling this method 'RunNormal'? Since its return type is String, I assume this isn't the delegate you used to run the thread. Also, I didn't quite understand, did you put a breakpoint at Process.Start and stepped through it in your debugger (F11 in Visual Studio)? How did the execution move?

Comment: Let me show you something about my application. When application runs, it will create some new process for updating,... (it work very good). After that, it will create a new thread to working. Main thread is loop and waiting here. One of the functions of the new thread is open (or execute) some thing and return result (success or not). Here is RunNormal function. About break point, I see it only run to start process and stop here although I press F11.

Comment: Mee to. Can't understand

Comment: Ooh, I have just realize that if i do this `/// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        //[STAThread]
        public static void Main()` it will work

Comment: [STAThread] is important. Are you saying, your problem is solved when adding this attribute?

Comment: yes that was solved by [STAThread]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Windows.Forms application and you try to show a message-box from a thread that is not the main user-interface thread, the behavior of the message-box is undefined. Meaning, it may or may not show, be inconsistent, or some other problem.

For instance, displaying a message-box from the BackgroundWorker's DoWork event may or may not work. In one case, the message-box-result was always cancel regardless of what button was clicked.

Therefore, if you are using a message-box just for debugging purposes, use a different technique. If you have to show a message-box, call it from the main user-interface thread.

A console-application should normally not have problems displaying message-boxes. Yet, I have had cases where I would have to sleep the thread for 100ms before the message-box call.

Note, as TomTom pointed out, the main user-interface thread is the application's Windows message loop. Which reminds me, I once had to create a Form in a Console application in order to create a Windows message loop, so my application could respond to Windows messages.

Comment: +1 for ointing out the problem oif a missing windows message loop.

Comment: @TomTom; that is what I couldn't remember, the Windows message loop. Thanks.

Comment: My problem is not show messagebox, it just be for checking. My question is why thread doesn't continue to work after call process.start(...)

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't the answer** - I can't put all this code in a comment...

This works for me. Tell me how your code differs from this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        const string OutputFile = @"E:\Output.txt";

        object _lock = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();

            Thread thread = new Thread(program.ThreadMethod);
            thread.Start(@"E:\Test.txt");

            thread = new Thread(program.ThreadMethod);
            thread.Start(@"E:\DoesntExist.txt");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        void ThreadMethod(object filename)
        {
            String result = RunNormal(filename as string);
            lock (_lock)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(OutputFile);
                if (!fi.Exists)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        fi.Create().Close();
                    }
                    catch (System.Security.SecurityException secEx)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An exception has occured: {0}", secEx.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                StreamWriter sw = fi.AppendText();
                sw.WriteLine(result);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

        string RunNormal(string fullfilename)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(fullfilename);
                return fullfilename + "|Success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return fullfilename + "|" + e.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output in Output.txt is:

```
E:\DoesntExist.txt|System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at Test.Program.RunNormal(String fullfilename) in E:\Projekti\VS2010\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 59
E:\Test.txt|Success
```

How much different is your code? Do you call some other methods? How do you process the results?

Comment: +1; Nice code. I like the user of the lock, FileInfo, and the try...catch block.

Comment: yes, in new project it works for me too. But in my big project, it doesn't. It's same as my function above

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Process.Start` works. Passing a filename is not good enough in some cases. In you sample code, you would have to set the use-shell property; otherwise, you would have to use `cmd start <filename>` or equivalent.

Therefore, just start NotePad.exe to make sure `Process.Start` works. If it does then your problem is the process command and command line.

Comment: same problem: `Process ptemp = new Process();
            ptemp.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";
            ptemp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            ptemp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            ptemp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            ptemp.Start();
            return "Success";` break point stop at `ptemp.Start();` and doesn't continue to run to return success string.